# iOS/Windows XML Encoding Issue for Unicode Characters

Tags: ios, .net, objective-c, xml, base64

I am working on a project that uses the iPhone/iPad to communicate to a Windows-based web service through one of Microsoft's ERP products.  The process is as follows:

1. Device queries the web service for data (for example, a customer list)
2. The web service queries the ERP database for information
3. The data is formatted into XML, the XML is compressed using .NET GZIP libraries, the compressed data (a string) is base 64 encoded, and then transmitted in a XML message structure back to the device
4. The device gets the base 64 encoded string, decompresses it using GZIP, and then parses the XML
5. The parsed data is stored in SQLite and displayed to the user, etc.

This all works great for everything *except* international characters.  For example:

**ERP/Windows sends (viewable in the ERP, in the database, in IE when saved as XML, or in Notepad as a UTF-8 encoded file and even an ANSI file):** Ä ä Ë ë Ï ï Ö ö Ü ü Ÿ ÿ

**iOS as the raw XML value:** \u201c\u00e4 \u201c\u00f1 \u201c\u00ef \u201c\u00bd \u201c\u00c5 \u201c\u00bb \u201c\u00fb \u201c\u2020 \u201c\u00a3 \u201c\u0152 \u2022\u02c6 \u201c\u008f

**iOS as the displayed value from the XML:** “ä “ñ “ï “½ “Å “» “û “† “£ “Œ •ˆ “

I'm sure this is an encoding thing at some level, but I have tried every method of encoding/decoding the values with no luck.  The XML is handled through the .NET 4.0 System.Xml.XmlDocument class and uses UTF-8.  iOS should be using UTF-8 to decode it.

For what it's worth, I've used TBXML and GDataXML to parse the XML data in iOS, and both return the same result.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  The only relevant code I can think of to share is the decompression code from a high level in iOS:

```
+ (NSString*) base64DecodeAndDecompress:(NSString*)compressedString
{
    NSData *compressedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:compressedString];

    if(compressedData == nil)
    {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    }

    NSData *uncompressedData = [QiwiGZIP gunzipData:compressedData];

    if(uncompressedData == nil)
    {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:uncompressedData    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Anyone else have a clue as to why this is happening?  I just tried the letter Ü in Windows, saved it as UTF-8 encoded XML (which I have verified is in fact UTF-8), and in iOS it shows up as “£ (the raw value is /u201c/u00a3).  I've tried every other NS encoding option under the sun to no avail (the value changes but it is still gibberish).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and pass it to XMLParser. And see if its working.

If you can parse the data. then you have to manually change the characters like,

```
[self replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;"  withString:@"&"  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];
    [self replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work... my issue is that for some unknown reason the characters are changed between Windows and iOS.  I'm not sure why iOS can't seem to handle the XML encoding.